# brew postgresql-upgrade-database fails on migrating and upgrading data

Tags: postgresql, macos, homebrew, postgresql-12

I've just sit down to my work, forgetting that I've upgraded brew in the 2020 – so of course I have a postgresql problem.

The last version I had was 12.x. Now I have 13.1 installed:

```
$ brew info postgres                                
Warning: Treating postgres as a formula. For the cask, use homebrew/cask/postgres
postgresql: stable 13.1 (bottled), HEAD
Object-relational database system
https://www.postgresql.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/13.1 (3,217 files, 42.6MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2020-12-26 at 14:36:54
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/postgresql.rb
License: PostgreSQL
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔
Required: icu4c ✔, krb5 ✔, openssl@1.1 ✔, readline ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
To migrate existing data from a previous major version of PostgreSQL run:
  brew postgresql-upgrade-database

This formula has created a default database cluster with:
  initdb --locale=C -E UTF-8 /usr/local/var/postgres
For more details, read:
  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-initdb.html

To have launchd start postgresql now and restart at login:
  brew services start postgresql
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
==> Analytics
install: 181,394 (30 days), 574,628 (90 days), 1,984,700 (365 days)
install-on-request: 176,623 (30 days), 554,629 (90 days), 1,910,250 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

Following the output, I'm trying to run `brew postgresql-upgrade-database`, but it does not work – here is the output:

```
$ brew postgresql-upgrade-database --debug --verbose
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb (Formulary::FormulaLoader): loading /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/postgresql.rb
==> Upgrading postgresql data from 12 to 13...
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@12/12.5/bin/pg_ctl -w -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
waiting for server to start....2021-01-04 17:37:33.282 CET [8190] FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
2021-01-04 17:37:33.282 CET [8190] DETAIL:  The database cluster was initialized with PG_CONTROL_VERSION 1300, but the server was compiled with PG_CONTROL_VERSION 1201.
2021-01-04 17:37:33.282 CET [8190] HINT:  It looks like you need to initdb.
2021-01-04 17:37:33.282 CET [8190] LOG:  database system is shut down
 stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
==> Moving postgresql data from /usr/local/var/postgres to /usr/local/var/postgres.old...
==> Creating database...
/usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/initdb /usr/local/var/postgres
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "nyc".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.UTF-8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /usr/local/var/postgres ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting default time zone ... Europe/Warsaw
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
syncing data to disk ... ok

initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.

Success. You can now start the database server using:

    /usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l logfile start

==> Migrating and upgrading data...
/usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/pg_upgrade -r -b /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@12/12.5/bin -B /usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin -d /usr/local/var/postgres.old -D /usr/local/var/postgres -j 4
Performing Consistency Checks
-----------------------------
Checking cluster versions                                   ok

The source cluster was not shut down cleanly.
Failure, exiting
Error: Upgrading postgresql data from 12 to 13 failed!
==> Removing empty postgresql initdb database...
==> Moving postgresql data back from /usr/local/var/postgres.old to /usr/local/var/postgres...
Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/pg_upgrade -r -b /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@12/12.5/bin -B /usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin -d /usr/local/var/postgres.old -D /usr/local/var/postgres -j 4` exited with 1.
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils.rb:303:in `safe_system'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/cmd/postgresql-upgrade-database.rb:126:in `block in postgresql_upgrade_database'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb:318:in `block in cd'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb:318:in `chdir'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb:318:in `cd'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/cmd/postgresql-upgrade-database.rb:125:in `postgresql_upgrade_database'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:124:in `<main>'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you been able to fix this?

Comment: Well, yes and no – I didn't have any valuable tables in there so I just abandoned them